# Scale edge /translate mouse position when moving between two monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse

I don't know how to phrase this question. I have a dual monitor setup with a 23" monitor above my 15.6" laptop. The edge between them obviously does not line up. Is it possible to have the mouse pointer move directly up between the monitors?

[image]

I'm on Windows 10. Both screens have the same resolution, so offsetting them in settings does not help:

[image]

I would need to have it like this:

[image]

Comment: If you go to Settings>displays (I think, I'm not currently on an English computer), you can move both screens around so the mouse lines up a bit better. For example, I use [these](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/isaacc623d4b8c1b0e5f997b03d7011d8af52.png) settings for [this](https://goo.gl/photos/S7Lh1JmewibTRRtC8) setup.

Comment: @cascer1 i know that i can offset it like this http://imgur.com/gyiBa6y , but  the resolution of both screens is the same, so it messes up the right side. What I would need is this: http://imgur.com/2hI0lH0 and I don't think it's possible

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize they had the same resolution. I'm afraid I can't help you then, sorry! Perhaps you could add this fact to the question so other people will know!

Comment: @cascer1 yeah I probably should have mentioned that in the question